# Sort listview by item checked

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, listview

I have a listview controll on a form, and all the columns have a hidden column to the left that I use to sort numbers correctly.

I would like to sort the items so that the checked items are first.

This is the code i use to sort right now, but it's not doing the job for the Checked item.

```
Private Sub lstProgramOrder_ColumnClick(ByVal ColumnHeader As MSComctlLib.ColumnHeader)
With lstProgramOrder

    .SortKey = IIf(ColumnHeader.Index = 1, 1, ColumnHeader.Index - 2)
    If .SortOrder = lvwAscending Then
        .SortOrder = lvwDescending
    Else
        .SortOrder = lvwAscending
    End If
    .Sorted = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sorting by the checkbox is not build into the listview. You could solve that by adding another invisible column next to the checkbox. You have to keep this in sync with the checkbox - this can be easily done by be event `ItemCheck` (in your case `lstProgramOrder_ItemCheck`).

You just have to make up your mind what you want to write into that new column. I have chosen to write `0` for checked and `1` for unchecked so that the checked items are sorted to the top.
Assuming that this dummy column is added next to the check-box (index 1):

```
Private Sub lstProgramOrder_ItemCheck(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    Item.ListSubItems(1) = IIf(Item.Checked, "0", "1")
End Sub
```

Then, in your `Column_Click`-routine, you have to set `.SortKey` to 1 if `ColumnHeader.Index = 1`